# hierarchical tables?

Tags: pagination, hierarchy

I have a shallow tree to display: action -> action item -> error

There can be millions of actions, tens to thousands of items per action and (usually) 0 to 1 errors per item. There can be also errors for an action (then I guess tens of them).

Obviusly with that amount of data actions and action items need to have some filtering.

The goal is to:

- quickly see the status of an action
- to browse errors for an action
- to see on which action items the action was executed

All of these 3 object have more properties than the columns I could fit resonably in a table (but not too much, 5-15 at the moment).

Do you have some pattern for showing such data? 
Would you use 2 paginated tables for actions and items, the items table depending on actions table?
Some kind of paginated tree? What is your suggestion for such kind of data?

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to answer without more context.
What are the types of actions, items, and errors?  What function/s are you trying to perform or what problem/s you are trying to solve?

It looks like you are wanting to show potentialy *thousands of millions* of entries.  Trying to show this quantity of data in a meaningful way is pointless without specialist visualization methods/tools such aggregate vizualizations or [treemaps](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/).

For an idea of just how pointless it is trying to use something like tables for this try doing a google search for 'music' - out of the *8,470,000,000* results you are only shown the first *10-100* items (depending on settings).  Even at 50 results I would consider this to be cognitive overload.

Tring to show this much data you will run into some of the following problems:

- clutter
- performance issues
- information loss

The *Visual Information Seeking Mantra* states:

> Overview First, Zoom and Filter, Details-on-Demand
>   
> *- Ben Shneiderman*

This was evolved to the *Visual Analytics Mantra*:

> Analyze First, Show the Important, Zoom, Filter and Analyze Further, Details-on-Demand
>   *- Daniel Keim*

What these break down into is that sometimes you need to use the power of the machine first and let it discover if there is anything interesting/useful to show before visualization is used.

See also [Fell in Love with Data](http://fellinlovewithdata.com/guides/how-do-you-visualize-too-much-data) and [Extreme Visualization:
Squeezing a Billion Records into a Million Pixels](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~ben/papers/Shneiderman2008Extreme.pdf)